# unique user on mobile site

Tags: django, mobile, ip, detection

I am developing a django web site to be used with *mobile phones* (not just smartphones), only in public places that have wireless (malls, resteraunts, etc.).

How can I follow unique users on my site? I want to mesure time spent, visit depth and so on BUT most of them will share the same IP.

**EDIT:** I will clearify myself: The site is to be used (without logging in) only in places with wireless. Smartphones will probably use the wireless, and non-smartphones will use their cellolar network. I'm looking for best practice to follow them uniqly regardless of the device/network.

Comment: Grabbing the user's mac address will come across as unethical, but it will accommodate your needs.

Comment: What model phones support wi-fi but aren't smart phones?

Comment: @Quentin - I edited my original question and added clearification

Answer (score 0):

Use the session ID. Don't track users if they're not logged in, track sessions.

Comment: They won't be logged in - so if someone calls them in the middle of surfing the session will end, would'nt it? How can I reduce double counting of same user?

Comment: Set a cookie. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#browser-length-sessions-vs-persistent-sessions

Answer (score 0):

Just post a cookie on the first visit, then update it regularly and keep track of it for your desired metrics.  It's not perfect, but nothing is in this space.

Comment: Can I use cookies in regular mobile phones (that use their browser)? I mean old, regular cell phones, not smartphones.

Comment: And what happens if someone calls them in the middle of surfing? are the cookies deleted when the browser suddenly closes?